# What about the Electric energy density of the toroid?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, confinement

[image]

But what about $U_{E}$, the electric field energy density?

Comment: It is zero. You have a static current in a material with net charge zero. This induces a static magnetic field, but not electric field.

Comment: Thank You :) But doesn't there need to be an electric field along the wire/coil in order to produce a current in the first place?

Comment: Nope. In an ideal conductor, a current can flow without an electric field.